# After getting the outcome of a Date.UTC() in Javascript, can I convert it back to a readable date format?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, highcharts, date-format

I am using the Highcharts JS Library and in particular one of the Highstock charts as the one here: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare and I am visualizing data of the form [Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minutes), value).

When someone clicks on a specific point I want to get the date that corresponds to that point. But, the Date.UTC() format gives back the number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1, 1970.

**My question is**: Is there a way to convert this number I get back to a date string I can read and understand? E.g. convert(1340628120000) get back -> 2012, 6 (month), 25(day), 15(hour), 42(minutes) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var utcSeconds = 1234567890;
var dateFormat = new Date(0); // The 0 sets the date to the epoch
dateFormat.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
```

Outputs: Fri Feb 13 2009 18:31:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

[date(); reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
Use [dateFormat](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#highcharts-object).
The HighCharts documentation is really good.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a Date variable with those milliseconds, you can use .toLocaleString() to turn it back into a readable format. Function listing [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp).

Use it like this:

```
var a = new Date(YOUR_UCT_VALUE);
a = a.toLocaleString();
```

An example output may be:

> Tue Aug 14 2012 15:24:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Not sure if that is what you want, but the built-in JavaScript Date has a lot of good functions, like getHours(), getMinutes(), etc. All you have to do is make a date object with the milliseconds you are getting. JavaScript does all the work for you after that.

Comment: Glad to help. Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp if you need any more help with the Date object.